# Django Rest Framework sql string query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I know if it is very easy to add API filtering to a rest API in Django.

```
/api?name=joseph&age=5. # I already have that
```

however, I am using a react package to generate the query, and it generates SQL string as such:

```
"name = 'joseph' AND age = 5"
```

I wonder what would be the easiest way to filter a table with SQL-string. 
The query could be nested with ORs and ANDs and NOTs. 
Please help ..

Answer (score 2):

> Performing raw sql queries in django is way easy in terms of how would
>   you perform.
>  Just you need to add raw in your queryset and perform
>   the model building.

**Below are the code snippet tor your reference**

```
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT id, first_name, last_name, birth_date FROM myapp_person')
...
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT last_name, birth_date, first_name, id FROM myapp_person')
...
```

**Example as per your requirement :**

```
name = 'joseph'
age = 5
sqlQuery = "SELECT * from <DBNAME> where name = "+name+" AND age = "+age
result = Person.objects.raw(sqlQuery)

# use of OR operator
name = 'joseph'
age = 5
result = Person.objects.filter(name=name) | Person.objects.filter(age=age) 

## use of AND operator
name = 'joseph'
age = 5
result = Person.objects.filter(name=name).filter(age=age)
```

Your can read here for [more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: so do you recommend to use a "post" to send the query string to the API, and use the string as sqlQuery in  "Person.objects.raw(sqlQuery)". since the other examples, you provided are hardcoded.

Comment: yes, it is better to send the params required as post request @JooJoo1020

Comment: would "Person.objects.raw(sqlQuery)" be smart enough to handle OR and AND and NOT ? so could the sqlQuery be something like  "name = 'joseph' or age >5" ?

Comment: both are okay, try it out, which one are you comfortable go with it, i have stated all the available choices @JooJoo1020